# scanf,back reference in awk

Tags: awk, posix

Is there any implementation of scanf()(like in C) in awk(POSIX)?

I know that awk does not have back reference like in sed and perl. 
What is the easiest way to simulate in awk?

Thanks

Nyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sprintf() , printf() may be what you are looking for. awk does not support backreferences however gawk's gensub(), or even gsub() can provide backreferences.

Backreferences are just storing the strings that are matched. So, making use of awk's capability to differentiate fields and field delimiters, using its internal variables like OFS,FS,ORS etc are the way to go.. eg

```
$ echo "test.txt" | sed 's/\(.*\).txt/\1.pdf/'
test.pdf

$ echo "test.txt" | awk -F"." '{$NF="pdf"}1' OFS="."
test.pdf
```

Of course, this is just a simple example. But you get the idea.

Comment: ya i know printf family in awk. but scanf??

Comment: you can use getline to take user input, then  use sprintf with the proper format specifier and store to variable

Comment: `gsub` doesn't provide backreferences. To get them directly, you need to use the gawk extension `gensub` (also available in some other awks, like BusyBox), or gawk's optional 3rd argument to `match`. You can *use* `gsub` to implement the same thing manually, which will be more portable; but, it's not a simple one-liner.